# How to send notification emails to users who flagged a node?

Tags: views, rules, 10

I want to notification email users who flagged a node.

Previously in Drupal 7, there was [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules) which is used to get flagger email and loop on them to send message.

Since Views Rules has no 8/9/10 version, I would like to know what alternative ways to do the same, i.e. send notification emails to users who flagged a node?

Comment: ECA is the new Rules. Please try this first. https://www.drupal.org/project/eca

Comment: @leymannx thanks for the advice, I'll check ECA module

Comment: I think ECA can do it. I found https://www.drupal.org/project/eca/issues/3357096 which describes my exact situation. It's still in progress due to ECA (execute view activity)